# How to create an udf for hive using python with 3rd party package like sklearn?

Tags: python, hive, package, udf

I know how to create a hive udf with `transform` and `using`, but I can't use `sklearn` because not all the node in hive cluster has `sklearn`.
I have an `anaconda2.tar.gz` with `sklearn`, What should I do ?

Comment: One solution is to copy all the source code to your udf.  I had a pig UDF that needed itertools but the python version we have is 2.6.6 which doesn't have itertools.  So I looked up the implementation of permutations and just put it in my UDF.  So instead of calling `itertools.permutations` I just called `permutations` that was defined in my UDF.  This may not be feasible if the function you need has many dependencies.  Another option is to install scikit-learn on each node.

Answer (score 0):

I recently started looking into this approach and I feel like the problem is not about to get all the 'hive nodes' having sklearn on them (as you mentioned above), I feel like it is rather a compatibility issue than 'sklearn node availability' one. I think sklearn is not (yet) designed to run as a parallel algorithm such that large amount of data can be processed in a short time.

---

What I'm trying to do, as an approach, is to communicate python to 'hive' through 'pyhive' (for example) and implement the necessary sklearn libraries/calls within that code. The rough assumption here that this 'sklearn-hive-python' code will run in each node and deal with the data at the 'map-reduce' level. 
I cannot say this is the right solution or correct approach (yet) but this is what I can conclude after searching for sometime.

Comment: thanks. I use `sklearn` for hive map-only job, so there is no communication between jobs (like reduce).

Comment: You can access hdfs files via 'spark' and then you can make use of 'spark-sklearn' (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/spark-sklearn/0.2.0). I would rather let python talk directly to hadoop and do all the necessary map-reduce works and then I work on the output data via spark-sklearn (data is large and stored in some data-warehouse in you machine). I believe spark-sklearn should take care of the data size.